# How to specificy path of new collection in Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongo-collection

I am running Mongo on Windows 10. Data access is made trugh Pymongo (Python). All my data is stored in an old large HDD, but I would like to have some smaller collection stored on a much faster SSD? When I create a new collection either trough Compass or Pymongo there is no option to specify the path on disk.

Is it possible to learn such power?

Comment: Just a hint, once you enabled `storage.directoryPerDB` you may also enable [`storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes) to move also the indexes to faster SSD.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have databases in different disks under the same dbPath , this is the option:

1. Add the option  [--directoryperdb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#std-option-mongod.--directoryperdb)  in the mongod config file or at startup.
2. db.createDatabase("newDatabase")
3. You will see inside the dbPath folder for the new database like:
   \dbPath\newDatabase
4. Stop the mongodb process.
5. Copy the content from \dbPath\neWDatabase to your SSD let say:
   ssd:\newData
6. make link to the folder with:

   ```
   mklink /d \newData \dbPath\newDatabase
   ```

or follow [this tutotial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/142868-mount-drive-folder-windows-10-a.html)

7. Start the mongodb process again.

Note:
As suggested by @Wermfried in the comment it is safe to have the option --directoryperdb set initially in the member before to get populated ...

Comment: I think you **cannot** just enable `storage.directoryPerDB` on an existing deployment and simply restart the database. All your data might get lost! The documentation clearly states "create a backup with `mongodump` .... restore with `mongorestore`" I don't think "*Copy the content from \dbPath\neWDatabase to your SSD let say: ssd:\newData*" will work

Comment: Previously in mmapv1 it was even posible to copy online , in WT it is abit tricky since WT write checksum in root dbPath. But you are right for the backup/restore even better to replicate to other member with directoryPerDB already set and later just remove the old member ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to move the collection to a brand new DB on another path